# What is this orange winged thing without studs?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

It looks like some really old flying thing.

Answer (score 8):

That piece is often used as a caterpillar track, or conveyor belt

[image]

It's hard to tell the colour in your photograph but it might be [Medium Dark Flesh (a.k.a. medium nougat)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57518#T=S&C=150&O=%7B%22color%22:%22150%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

At the bottom of this page there are [three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57518&in=S) which use this piece in that colour.

If you look carefully you should see the number "57518" shaped into the piece. Almost all Lego pieces have that a code on them that you can use to find them on sites like [BrickSet](http://brickset.com) or [BrickLink](http://bricklink.com).